# Once the shutdown button is pressed on windows and it displays shutting down screen, is it possible to cancel the shutdown?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, shutdown, autohotkey

Once the `Shutdown` button is pressed (mistakenly or intentionally) on Windows (10/11), it displays text "Shutting Down" with circle(s) spinning animation. At this stage, pressing most keyboard shortcuts don't seem to work. After mistakenly pressing `Shutdown`, tried different keyboard shortcuts such as `Alt + Ctrl + Del`, but PC didn't respond to it, and it ultimately powered off.

Wondering now, if it is possible to cancel the shutdown process once it starts displaying "Shutting Down" screen. It is going to be useful in scenarios when `Shutdown` button is mistakenly pressed.

Comment: What does this have to do with autohotkey? There is a window when you'd be able to fire a `shutdown /a` but usually you won't be able to abort at that point. At that point applications have begun to close. You can get an idea about this my having e.g. a notepad instance open with a save dialog. Usually Windows should allow you to cancel the shutdown in this case.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can change function of shutdown button,
ref:
Shut down, sleep, or hibernate your PC - Microsoft Support:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/shut-down-sleep-or-hibernate-your-pc-2941d165-7d0a-a5e8-c5ad-8c972e8e6eff

[image]